# simulating rainfall in Python

Tags: python

I have been trying to get this done for the past few weeks and i have been messing with my code but nothing i do seems to help. I am having trouble with coding the total rainfall, average rainfall and checking if there is a drought of more than 12 days and a flood of more than 5 days with rain equaling at least 6 inches. Please help me. I am doing this in Python 3.3. And I am doing a simulation for 108 days and then for a century. I would really appreciate some help. When I run this program I get a number for totalRain but it is not the rainfall added up. For the flood and I am suppose to use if statements for the flood part but I'm not sure how. And for drought I need to show if there was a drought which is 12 or more days with no rain.

```
import random 
import math 

def rainFallAmount(x): 
    if chance<=0.71: 
        rainfall=0; 
    elif chance<=0.78: 
        rainfall=0.5; 
    elif chance<=0.85: 
        rainfall=0.75; 
    elif chance<=0.92: 
        rainfall=1.0; 
    elif chance<=0.98: 
        rainfall=1.5; 
    else: 
        rainfall=2.0; 
    return rainfall; 


totalRain = 0; 
day=109; 
num_days_no_rain = 0; # max_days_without_rain 
days_of_drought = 0; # days_not_raining 
days_over15 = 0; 
days_rained = 0; 
years = 100; 
#last_5_days = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; 
days = 36500; 
max_drought = 0; 

#This for loop is for 108 days. 
for day in range(109): 
    chance=random.uniform(0,1); 
    rainfall=rainFallAmount(chance); 
    print(rainfall); 
#last_5_days=[day%5]; 
#last_5_days= rainfall; 
#math.fsum([last_5_days]) > 6 
#there was a flood 
    if rainfall<0.5: 
        days_of_drought+=1; 
        days_rained=0; 
        num_days_no_rain+=1; 
    if days_of_drought>max_drought: 
        max_drought=days_of_drought; 
    else: 
        days_rained+=1; 
        if rainfall>=1.5: 
            days_over15+=1; 
            if rainfall>=0.5: 
                totalRain+=1; 
                avgRain=totalRain/day; 

print(rainfall); 
print("The number of days the rain was greater than 1.5 inches: ", days_over15); 
print("The longest period of no rain is: ", num_days_no_rain); 
print("The total rain for", day, "days is:", totalRain); 
print("The average rain per day is: ", avgRain); 
print("The longest period of rain is: ", days_rained); 
print("Longest drought was: ", days_of_drought,"days"); 

#This for loop is for a whole century. 
for years in range(36500): 
    chance=random.uniform(0,1); 
    rainfall =rainFallAmount(chance); 
    print(rainfall); 
    if rainfall == 0: 
        days_of_drought+=1; 
        days_rained=0; 
    if days_of_drought>max_drought: 
        max_drought=days_of_drought; 
        days_rained+=1 
        if rainfall>=0.5: 
            totalRain+=1; 
            avgDayRain=(totalRain/day;)
            avgYearRain=(totalRain/years); 


print("The longest period of no rain is: ", noRain); 
print("The total rain for", years, "years is:", totalRain); 
print("The average rain per year is: ", avgYearRain); 
print("The average rain per day is: ", avgDayRain);
```

Comment: Your problem is a very complex one and should be better split into smaller solvable parts that reside in different questions. It will be easier both for you to formulate your question and for other users to follow you.

Comment: Rainfall Simulation is mine as well but I figured I might need to repost to get an answer. I just need some help and would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the variable totalRain to contain the sum of all rainfall in your simulation. There are numerous problems in your code, I will address a few of them only.

The problem is in this if statement:

```
if days_of_drought>max_drought: 
    max_drought=days_of_drought; 
else: 
    days_rained+=1; 
    if rainfall>=1.5:    <--- HERE
        days_over15+=1; 
        if rainfall>=0.5: 
            totalRain+=1; <-- HERE
            avgRain=totalRain/day;
```

In english, this says: "If the rainfall is more than 1.5 inches, then add 1 to the sum of all rainfall." You probably meant it to say: "Add **rainfall** to the sum of all rainfall. (No matter how little it rains)."

Besides this, the `if rainfall>=0.5` does not make sense, since it is already in the branch where the rainfall is above 1.5 and therefore surely above 0.5.

As a side note, you don't need any of your semicolons.

Try and see if something like the following is what you want:

```
totalRain+=rainfall
if days_of_drought>max_drought: 
    max_drought=days_of_drought
else: 
    days_rained+=1
    if rainfall>=1.5:
        days_over15+=1
        avgRain=totalRain/day
```

That last statement for calculating `avgRain` seems questionable to me. You might want to think about exactly what that variable means and how this should be correctly calculated.